# Running python inside pycharm works, but not from terminal

Tags: python, selenium, pip, pycharm

I have written basic selenium script inside Pycharm. When running it inside Pycharm it all works. But when I want to run the program from the terminal with python webscraper.py it returns:

```
from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

even though I have selenium installed via Pycharm as well as

```
pip install selenium
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in c:\users\philipp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\users\philipp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from selenium) (1.26.6)
```

I have Python 3.8 installed:

```
> C:\Users\PycharmProjects\>python
Python 3.8.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Dec 26 2020, 04:30:06) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I have used conda back in the days. So there is some kind of mixup going on.
Any idea how to make it work from the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing **selenium** using **pip** using **python** (I hope that makes sense). So instead of:

```
pip install selenium
```

You should use:

```
python -m pip install selenium
```

Or:

```
python3 -m pip install selenium
```

Edit: Like **Artoiss** said, it is probably an environment issue.

Comment: Hey, thank you all. Using python -m did the trick. thx

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `selenium` in terminal with:

```
pip3 install selenium
```

You are having two different virtual environments. When you are using Pycharm you probably use virtualenv which is made inside Pycharm. However, same environment is not used in your terminal.

**You can also activate you Pycharm environment in terminal.**

In Pycharm go to `File->Settings->Project:(your project name)->Python interpreter`. From there you can see the path of your project's virtual environment. Normally venvs are installed in `C:\Users\yourUsername\PycharmProjects\yourProjectName\venv\Scripts`.

[image]

**To activate this venv in terminal you can just write to terminal:**

`C:\Users\yourUsername\PycharmProjects\yourProjectName\venv\Scripts\activate.bat`

After that your terminal uses same Python environment as your Pycharm project and your code should run without problems!

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm by default intergrates with virtaulenv.
If you want to run the script outside the pycharm.

**Check this docs:** https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html